# Boolean Functions and using rules ..

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is the function $p \wedge (~\neg(\neg p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge q))$ equal to the function $p \wedge q$?

Do I need to provide a truth table for this, or do I have to use the rules (for Manipulating functions) to see if it is equal?

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is, then the answer to your second question depends on your teacher.

Comment: what if by using formula, not by truth table.

Comment: Either path will answer the question.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} & p \wedge (~\neg(\neg p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge q))\\ \\ 
&\equiv p \land ((\lnot \lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q))\\ \\ 
&\equiv p \land ((p \land \lnot q)\lor (p \land q))\\ \\
&\equiv p \land (p\land (\lnot q \lor q))\\ \\
&\equiv p \land (p \land T)\\ \\ 
&\equiv p\land p\\ \\
&\equiv p
\end{align}$$

Now, review your notes and text to find the justification for each step above.